# How to get POST data in request?

Tags: node.js, express, web

I'm using Express+Node.js now. I need to extract POST data from a request to make Log-in process.

I want to get POST data in request but there was nothing in req.body when I ran my code.(Always return {} )

I'm relatively new to NodeJs, so precise help is welcome. Please help me.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var crypto=require('crypto');
var passport=require('passport');
var localStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;

var mysql=require('mysql');

router.use(bodyparser.json());
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());

var config={
 ///config
};


const conn = new mysql.createConnection(config);

conn.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Cannot Connect to database : ');
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        console.log('Success to connect database');
    }
});

var isAuthenticated =function(req,res,next){ 
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){ 
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/');
}

router.post('/login',function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports=router;
```

html form code

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form" method="post" action="/login">
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "이메일 양식 확인">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Email"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="비밀번호 양식 확인">
                        <span class="btn-show-pass">
                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="password">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <button class="login100-form-btn">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to send a body in your request, something like the postman tool can help you.
You need to add a body to your request and send it to your http://localhost: 3000

Answer (score 0):

Use POSTMAN, insert url like this `http://10.10.0.1:3000/user/login`
in Body section select *raw* type **Json**
then insert

```
{
    "email_id" : "abc123@xyz.in",
    "password" : "Test@123"
}
```

Comment: I did it already, but there is no body information in my request. Is there a mistake about bodyparser in my code?

Comment: change form action url action="http://10.10.0.1:3000/login" either IP or **localhost:3000/login**